# Opening vbp Visual Basic Project

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I have got some old sources written in Visual Basic. There are `*.bas`, `*.cls`, `*.frm` and `*.vbp` files. As I understand, `vbp` is a project file. But I cannot open it with my Visual Studio 2008.

What version of VS should I install to open `*.vbp` file? Google says it is Visual Studio 6, but I am not sure and I **cannot find** Visual Studio 6 for downloading. Is there any publicly available free edition of Visual Studio 6 with Visual Basic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

vbp is indeed a VB 5/6 Project File.

VS6/VB5/VB6 are not free, so if you want to build the project you will need to spend $5 on ebay.

The [VB5 Control Creation Edition](http://www.thevbzone.com/vbcce.htm) (build COM components only) was the only free version MS released.

Older versions of VS.net included a way to import a VBP and upgrade it to VB.NET, but YMMV (significantly).

Edit; If you just want to look at the source/project structure all the files except .frx are plain ascii.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an MSDN subscription, then VB6 is [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx) as a free download. Otherwise [try ebay](http://popular.ebay.com/computers-networking/visual-basic.htm) like Alex suggests, but it usually costs significantly more than $5.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft recommends users get a 3rd party conversion program called ArtinSoft, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff793478

Comment: is this one is open source ?

Comment: You can get a free trial of it to convert a few thousand lines. It looks pretty promising (if you have a big project)

Comment: This link gives a 404 now.

Answer (score 2):

To get a working copy of visual basic follow the following steps.

1. after much research I found out that the original Vb6 was distributed as a disk set, all CD's are just ISO files built up of folders and files. You can get a copy of an original ISO here. There is a google drive version floating around on the web of the ISO but personally that just seems really sketchy to me.
   https://winworldpc.com/product/microsoft-visual-bas/60

2. in order to use the ISO you will need to unzip the ISO with WinRar, so download a copy of WinRar (its a widely used file archiver tool)
3. follow the install instructions here https://youtu.be/LXvd8IRw_ZI
   "How to Install Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows 7/8/8.1/10" by "Matthew Marcelo"
   ** be sure to run the installation as administrator ** `.\Micrsosoft Visual Basic 6.0\extracted\SETUP.EXE`
4. after getting everything installed I realized I needed a copy of the MSDN library (version October 1999) which is the developer documentation for using VB6, that is found here https://winworldpc.com/product/msdn/october-1999

--

if you are like me and had to get VB6 working because of a very old legacy project and you had no clue what .OCX (controller) files were, and you got a bunch of error messages when you open the main project .VBP file, when you get ahold of the files and install them, installing them as admin usually does the trick by making a batch file, or running an administrator powershell/cmd window

```
regsvr32.exe \path\to\file.ocx
```

Answer (score 1):

When opening the vbp file which is the project file, you will most likely have an import wizard show up, which after trying to import the project it will likely tell you there are a bunch of dependencies vb6 used to use which .net does not and will error out. You need to have vb5/6 installed or at least the dependency files installed in order to proceed with the import. You can view source code from the plain ascii text files of the .frM files.

Comment: +1 Also be aware that importing (or migrating) VB6 code to VB2008 can require a great deal of effort. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=vb6-migration&sort=votes&pagesize=15

Answer (score 0):

you need Visual Basic, not Visual Studio to open these files. or you can open it using a normal text editor like sublime text file separately. but if you want to open it like a project then you should use Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 / 5.0 . There is a portable version too.

If you still want to open .vbp file using visual studio try to use VB tools for Visual Studio. I think it will help you.