# Open .vbp,.frm files in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I've some .vbp,.frm files and i want to open them with VB 6.0 but i am using Windows 8.1  is there any version of Visual Basic that is compatible with Windows 8.1.Please do suggest me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its not a problem, Visual Basic 5 & 6 run on Windows 8.

Comment: Those files are text files. You can use notepad to look.

Comment: See the question about what IDE to use for VB6 projects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959427/opening-vbp-visual-basic-project

Comment: See this question about where to get the VB6 IDE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617486/development-environment-for-vbp-files

Comment: And finally see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495680/installation-of-vb6-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-or-windows-10) about how to get the VB6 IDE working on Windows 8.1 (the steps also apply for Windows 7 and 10)

Answer (score 0):

Whats not working? Microsoft is supporting run time files for at least a few more years works up to 10 and maybe will be for a few more versions, install vb 6 and it should have no problem running unless the systems messed up.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by others, the VB6 development tools can be installed and work (with limitations) on all versions of Windows Longhorn (including Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, on up through Windows 10).  Most of the limitations are project types rendered useless when Microsoft ripped away the infrastructure for them as they mutated IE and IIS over the years with little regard.

So without a license for VB6 or preferably VS6 there isn't much you can do with these files.  If the projects are fairly simple you might get somewhere trying to make the completely unsupported VB5 work if you have a license for that, or if the project files are for even simpler applications VB5CCE might be of some limited use if you have that.

But in general there are no other products that can use these files to any useful extent.  So as already covered many times in other questions here and elsewhere you need VB6/VS6 and the only remaining source is an MSDN Subscription or used or remaindered copies that may be for sale here and there.

Comment: @vishal_raut:  frm files are not so difficul to read: you can extract the design of the form (control, positions), and you can "simply" copy & paste the code. BUT, if there are some VBx specials (control arrays e.g.) you have to rewrite a painful amount of code.

Comment: That is true as far as it goes, but it doesn't go very far.  There are expensive 3rd party suites that attempt to "upgrade" VB6 projects to other languages but at best these hit the easy 80% leaving the much harder 20% up to manual intervention.  Few of these even do a decent job extracting binary resources from VB6 project files.  If these vampires can't do it what chance does some random guy have on his own?

Comment: There are tools, and yes, they can do the easy part. But the easy part can be done by an average developer by himself. BUT: If he uses some 3rd party COM components, which may not exisit anymore, he is doomed to rewrite anyway. The easisest way would be to get an MSDN Abo and download the VS6 Suite (maybe someone knows if this is still possible), the latest SP (=6), and install it in a virtual machine and work with the old code diret - ok, does not help when he is missing som 3rd Party COM components)