# tools available to run a vb 6 projects?

Tags: vb6

i have a vb 6 prroject itried to open it on vs 2013 by installing extension name as vb 6 for visual studio from console manager now i the error is that extension is not compatible so i google that its mean vb 6 project cannot be upgraded so instead of wasting time i am asking is there any tool to run vb 6 win form gui app so that i can open my source code , can you give me that downloading link of tool too

i have extension frm , with my forms in vb 6 so please

as vb 6 is not a part of .net technology so it will never run on visual studio

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959427/opening-vbp-visual-basic-project?rq=1

Comment: VB6 is available via MSDN.  I have it running on Win7, Win8 and Win10 (it takes a bit of finnagling).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:  VB6 is long past end of life from Microsoft.

None of Microsoft's existing tools will even read VB6 sensibly.  VB.net is NOT VB6 in any way or form.

If you want to develop/enhance/extend a VB6 program, you need a VB6 development environment.   Some say this is available via MSDN.  Otherwise it is pretty hard to find.

As a practical matter, if you want to move this VB6 program to a modern language, you'll need to find a [migration tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460977/120163)/vendor/service that understands VB6 to do this for you, or do it yourself (which usually fails unless the project is really small).  And yes, converting the forms is hard.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fork over the cash for an MSDN subscription to get access to the necessary tools it takes time to develop proficiency in a new language and those tools for using it.  Many companies take the smarter path and hire a contractor with both the tools and the experience to handle maintenance of their legacy VB6 portfolio.

This saves the expense of porting such applications to another language and limits the risk of such a port having data-destroying flaws.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VS2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bszew91f(v=vs.120).aspx), but you'll probably still have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need this VB6 code for, you might be able to copy it into the VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) section of a Microsoft Office document. As I understand it, VBA is nearly identical to VB6 from a programming-language and capability point of view.

Note that this would *not* allow you to compile code to a standalone EXE or DLL, but if you don't need to do that it might be an acceptable workaround for not having the VB6 development tools.

Here is a link to Microsoft's primer on VBA: [MSDN VBA Primer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd721892%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Also, be aware that most VB6 source code files (excepting FRX files) are plain text so if you just need to read them, you can use any text editor.